# How does CI/CD work for HTTPS web servers?

Tags: nginx, continuous-integration, ssl-certificate, web-deployment, continuous-delivery

I am totally new to CI/CD and moderately experienced with web development. I searched Google and StackOverflow but couldn't find an answer or a guide on this matter.

I would like to setup a dev environment for an HTTPS web server that allows me to test my changes before I deploy them. Right now, I am using NodeJS to listen to a port on the server that includes the SSL certificate. I wait for midnight when there are no active users to change the code. I stop the node server, edit the code and run the node server again.

I am using external APIs that require HTTPS so I can not test my code locally. If the website is up all the time, and I need HTTPS connection to test the changes, how can I actually edit the code and see the changes?

I looked online and found tools like Jenkins and Kubernetes for CI/CD and they have tests but not exactly what I need.

I found a solution using NGINX with load balancing that suggested these steps: remove a server from the balancer, make the changes, test the code, add the server back to the load balancer, do the same for the remaining servers.

However, this does not work for me since there has to be an SSL certificate in the server and only the initial server that runs NGINX has the certificate. If I connect to the IP address of each server, then external APIs do not work since the connection is HTTP now.

How can I apply CI/CD to an HTTPS web server? How can I edit the code and see the changes without stopping the live server?